# Where does top / gnome-system-monitor get its information about cpu usage?

Tags: linux, gnome, top

I am curious where gnome-system-monitor and top (the command line tool) get their information about the CPU usage in %. Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `/proc`.

At `/proc/[PID]/stat` you have kernel statistics about a given process.

You can find more information on about what to look for on the stat file on [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux/1424556#1424556).

I'm not sure if it's a reasonable assumption but probably the current CPU usage is (100% - [the cpu usage for the idle process]).